# bootstraps modal event 'shown' not firing on IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In my django site I am using bootstrap's modal to show a form. However, part of that form is a date-field and I want to use jQuery UI datepicker. Since the form is fetched dynamically, I looked into using bootstrap's modal events to apply the functionality after the modal is being displayed. I did this:

```
$('#myModal').modal().on('shown', function() { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

This is working on chrome, but not on IE 8. I need to support it, and having the datepicker is critical. I don't see any error messages, so I think my code is ok, and adding a few alert messages told me that in IE the event isn't even firing. What should I do?

I am using bootstrap 2.2

p.s. I already tried switching places and doing `.modal()` after `.on('shown'` but to no avail. The page is rendered in standarts mode and with IE8 compatibility, I made sure of that. I'm guessing this is a problem with IE I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function() { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}).modal();
```

I solved the same problem with this solution. Show this [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3360#issuecomment-5600575).

Comment: You're calling modal on the datepicker field why would that work? The link doesn't have any solution and I've seen question here on SO where the answer was the order of the events but that is not the issue here

Comment: No. I'm calling modal from "#myModal" selector, not from datepicker. I'm doing just you like to do, init datepicker after show the modal because the modal's html is rendered dynamically. Try that.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I already tried switching places. That did not work for me.

Comment: I did however, managed to make it work by binding the event to the document itself and using 'show', but that brought on additional problems, see my question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181270/ie-hates-my-modal-window-events