# IE hates my modal window events

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website and am using Twitter Bootstrap modal.js as part of my project. And as usual, IE is causing some trouble.

I have a few buttons, that when clicked each fetches a different form through ajax, fills the modal with the form, and brings it up. Since they are being fetched dynamically I need to update some of the fields with additional scripts (jQuery UI datepicker for example) after the modal is being fetched. Immediately after the ajax call does not work so I need to use the modal events.

This works on chrome:

```
$('#myModal').modal().on('shown', function() {
    $('#id_date').datepicker();
});
```

However, IE does something weird. For it to work I had to bind the listener to the 'show' event ('shown' doesn't work) and to the document instead of the modal.

Inside a document.ready:

```
$(document).on('show', function() {
    $('#id_date').datepicker();
});
```

After clicking a button:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

But here's the kicker - this doesn't work either **unless** I add an `alert('hello');` above the `.datepicker()`. Why does alert change anything? I don't know, but then it also stacks up - every time you click on one of the buttons you get more alerts, i.e. the first time one alert, the second time two alerts and so on.

I am using bootstrap 2.2 and IE8 (standards mode, there's also a meta to make sure the page is rendered as IE8 and not an older version). I have no idea what's the problem here, please help!

**Update**

So I narrowed it down a little. This isn't anything to do with the 'shown' or 'show' events or what it is binded for. It's a lot weirder. This is what I ended up doing:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
     if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
         alert('Hey! you should really use Chrome!');
     }
     $('#id_date').datepicker();
     $('#id_tags').chosen(); 
});


$('#button1').on('click', function() {
     $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Without the alert message, IE doesn't run the datepicker and chosen code that comes immediately afterward. *why would a simple alert have such an impact?*

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: To be honest I think it's a race condition, try adding a delay to see if it helps, if it does, chain the events with proper callbacks

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Yes! That has to be it! Would you post an answer so I'd mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After reconsideration this seems to be a race condition

I don't have a real answer on *why* this is happening, *other than IE being a pain with different jQuery versions and html5 attributes..*

However, I *do* remember having had a similar issue a few months ago, if I'm not mistaken, adding the following line to your html head section should help a lot.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, This looks very promising! Sadly I won't be able to test it out before tomorrow. I'll check back and update, really hope this will work

Comment: So the html5shim didn't really help, but thanks anyway. I updated my quetion, I'd love it if you'd take a look and see if you have anything else to contribute